# Oracle : How to get max column length from dynamically generated query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose I have a query like

```
select a.column1, b.column2, substr(b.column3,instr(b.column3,',')) as Column3
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.column1 = b.column1
```

How do I get the max character length for each column of this query ?

If tableA and tableB are defined as

```
tableA ( column1 VARCAHR2(100))     
tableB ( column1 VARCAHR2(100), column2 INTEGER, column3 VARCAHR2(5000))
```

I would like to get those data :

```
COLUMN1 : 100
COLUMN2 : 10
COLUMN3 : 5000
```

Keep in mind this is a dynamic query, there might be any number of columns from any number of tables within limitation.

Comment: So you want column length to be populated for all the rows?

Comment: I believe, in your case, [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) could do the trick, e.g. `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(a.column1)) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS max_a_column1_len ...`.

Comment: @Utsav ,  I want max possible character length for each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table for a moment from your query (CTAS) and after that use `user_tab_columns` to get column's `data_length` for your new table.

```
create table temp as 
select a.column1, b.column2, substr(b.column3,instr(b.column3,',')) as Column3
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.column1 = b.column1
    --No need for store the data, unless you want the maximum size of current data.
    and 1 = 0;

select column_name, data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEMP';

drop table temp;
```

It's quite easy and you do not need to care what you have exactly in your query. Oracle will figure out this for you.

BTW. The max size of `VARCHAR2` is 4000. You cannot have 5000 unless you are using 12c with extended data types.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to access the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` metadata table to get these column lengths

Below is an example query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      ,CHAR_LENGTH
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('tableA', 'tableB')
   AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')
;
```

If you need the above in your generated query, then it would need to change to something like below

```
select a.column1
     , b.column2
     , substr(b.column3,instr(b.column3,',')) as Column3
     , (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableA' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column1') AS column1_size
     , (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableB' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column2') AS column2_size
     , (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableB' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column3') AS column3_size
  from tableA a
     , tableB b
 where a.column1 = b.column1
```

The above is one way of doing this just as an example. Depending on what you are trying to do and how you are generating the query, I think you would want to get the column sizes in a separate query like the first one, since you already know the column and table names when generating the query.

Hope this helps..